# Matrices and Transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

Proposition. If $c$ is a number, show that $^{t}\left( cA\right) =c^{t}A.$

My question is that what is $c^{t}$ mean/say? Can you give example about $c$ and $c^{t}$?

Comment: do you mean $(cA)^t=cA^t$?

Comment: I dont understand the question but if $c$ is a number think of it as a 1x1 matrix. Then $c^t=c$

Answer (score 1):

In your notation it looks like the superscript "$^t$" **precedes** the object that it applies to. So, using parentheses to make it explicit, you want to show
$$^t(cA) = c( ^tA)$$
In words, "the transpose of ($c$ times $A$) is $c$ times (the transpose of $A$)".

Comment: I agree with you. There should be mistake (it is from Lang's **Linear Algebra** p.28)

Comment: It's not necessarily a mistake. I've seen similar notation before. Just look and see if Lang defines the transpose operator in that way. It could be used to distinguish it from an ordinary exponent, for example. In algebra, it is not uncommon to denote the image of $a$ under the map $\phi$ by $a\phi$, although I personally dislike that notation.

Comment: Yet, solution (by Skarchi) says that If $A=(a_{ij} )$ and $b_{ji}=a_{ij}$ then by definition we have
$^{t}(cA) = (cb_{ji} )$; so $c^{t}A=c(b_{ji})=(cb_{ji})=^{t}(cA)$.

Comment: Yes, ıt definitely  is NO $c^{t}$. This is $^{t}A$.